# Inserting into table with special conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I hope you help me out a little with my sql problem. I am using SQL Server 2008. So what I basically have are two tables

1. Table (MAIN TABLE) that consists of the following information:

id|QUANTITY|AMOUNT|DATE

example:

```
iD|mainQuantity|mainAMOUNT|DATE      | subQUANTITY      | subAMOUNT |
-----------------------
1 |    200     | 1200     |02.02.2016|     ?            |      ?
2 |    500     | 700      |20.03.2016|     ?            |      ?

2. Table (SUB TABLE) that consists of the following information:

 ID|subQUANTITY|subAMOUNT|DATE
 -----------------------
 1 |    280 | 1600 |07.02.2016
 2 |    140 | 110  |22.02.2016
```

So my problem is.

I want to implement the following logic into my MS SQL Server.

1. Check if the DATE of the FIRST row in the SUB TABLE is identically with the date of the first row of the main Table or between 02.02.2016 and 20.03.2016 (Information of the Main Table).
   If it is correct, then insert INTO MAINTABLE the VALUES of first row in the Column QUANTITY and AMOUNT in the Maintable into the subquantity and subamount UNTIL it reaches the maximum value of mainQuantity and mainAMOUNT.
   The     residual amount and the remaining quantity should be insertet into the next row into the column subquantity and subamount.
2. Do the same thing for every next row and insert the remaining quantity and amount in the next row of the main table.

example:

first ROW: ID1 -> DATE 07.02.2016 -> check if it is equal or between 02.02.2016 and 20.03.2016. -> YES IT is. -> INSERT INTO MAINTABLE:

result:

```
ID|mainQUANTITY|mainAMOUNT|DATE      | subQUANTITY      | subAMOUNT |
-----------------------
1 |    200     | 1200     |02.02.2016|     200          |      1200
2 |    500     | 700      |20.03.2016|     220          |      510
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention it: I dont have 1 column for the Date. I have two columns. A startingDate and an EndDate. The Date condition logic is still the same. So the logic should check if a date is exaclte equal to starting date or between startingDate and EndDate

I tried to do my best to explain it as easy as possible.I hope you understand the logic :)
Iam not that good in T-SQL that I program it by myself. So that is why I really badly hope that you can please help me.

Thank you very much for your time and your effort.

Comment: The way this is shown in your example is that subQuantity and subAmount are columns in the main table. Is this correct? In that case, you'll be wanting to do an update instead of an insert. Just to confirm before I answer this in full.

Comment: Thank you for your help Peter. Well, actually the result should by shown in a new table. I forgot to mention it. So I need a new resultTable with the following information 

ID|mainQUANTITY|mainAMOUNT|    DATE      | subQUANTITY      | subAMOUNT |

Comment: Thanks Jinks. Another question: Can you rely in the main records being in date order with ID sequential?

Comment: As far as I understand your question, no it is not sequential

Comment: Hello Peter, did you found a solution?